# Mongoose not saving all fields

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I am trying to save an new document record and some of the fields are being omitted and I have not been able to figure out why.

Here I am setting my order object

```
var obj = new Order(orderObj);
console.log('orderObj', orderObj);
console.log('obj', obj);
```

output from console.log:

```
orderObj { customerId: '5806e2a1759fd9ad7a1f60eb',
  products: 
   [ { productId: '5806e7e3d0073cb4d2946aad',
       customerPrice: 100,
       notes: 'test',
       originalPrice: 99.95,
       priceOverride: true } ],
  notes: 'some optional order notes',
  createdBy: 'test',
  total: 99.95 }

obj { customerId: 5806e2a1759fd9ad7a1f60eb,
  notes: 'some optional order notes',
  createdBy: 'test',
  _id: 5808171e802121505e33b252,
  shipped: false,
  shippedDate: 2016-10-20T01:00:14.019Z,
  status: 'Created, Not Shipped',
  products: 
   [ { productId: 5806e7e3d0073cb4d2946aad,
       _id: 5808171e802121505e33b253,
       quantity: 1 } ] }
```

Here is my schema:

```
var orderSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  customerId: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Customer'},
  products: [{
    productId: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Product'},
    quantity: { type: Number, default: 1 },
    originalPrice: { Type: Number },
    customerPrice: { Type: Number },
    priceOverride: { Type: Boolean, default: false },
    notes: { Type: String }
  }],
  notes: String,
  status: { type: String, default: "Created, Not Shipped" },
  orderDate: { type: Date },
  shippedDate: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  shipped: { type: Boolean, default: false },
  total: {Type: Number, default: 0.00 },
  createdBy: { type: String }
}, schemaOptions);
```

I cannot figure out why total and product fields (originalPrice, priceOverride) are being dropped from the mongoose Schema instance object.

Answer (score 3):

Of course I figured it out right after I posted this question.  The type in the Schema was listed as Type instead of type.

Answer (score 2):

[this answer is for the record]
I had same kind of problem and in a schema where `maxconnections` and `roomNo` were not being saved,
I had schema

```
maxconnections: {type: Number | String },
roomNo: {type: Number | String },
```

changed it to

```
maxconnections: {type: Number },
roomNo: {type: String},
```

and now it works fine (!._.)

Answer (score 0):

Also, when sending a request using postman, use content-type as  **JSON**

Otherwise, data in fields will not get stored

[image]